# amCharts: sorting numeric categoryAxis

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I need categoryAxis sorted in ascending order (from -10 to 4) instead of how it is sorted in the image below:
[image]
I have checked data and column that I am using (categoryField) is integer and not string, it is not even in this order. It is in descending order and AmChart changes the order (from 4 to -10) and treats it like 2 different value series.

I looked at AmCharts API (https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis) but doesn't seems to have a property I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out - basically AmCharts don't do anything with the Y-Axis (CategoryAxis) data. It just charts in the same order as it comes. Unfortunately there is no way to sort the data but my initial opinion about AmCharts sorting it for me was wrong. It was `$.parseJSON(rawData);` jQuery's parseJSON function which was screwing up order of my JSON array, which I figured out and resorted it.

I hope it helps someone who is lost.

Took 30 minutes to find an answer, posted on SO as I was in a bit hurry.

Comment: To add from my response on the support thread for anyone else that's looking - XY charts are typically better suited for data that require numeric X and Y axes.  You'll still need to sort the data if you're connecting the points (i.e. `lineAlpha` is not set to 0) as it draws the connections between the points in the order the dataProvider points appear.